# Best way to set a value to any field in Javascript without knowing beforehand if it's going to be a input, select, textarea, radio, or checkbox field

Tags: javascript, typescript, forms, input, webforms

The project I'm working on builds on a tool that allows users to create forms and add fields to it. Some of the fields are baked in already (e.g State, Province) and have unique targetable names classes that are shared across all forms "e.g. id='region'". However as each user adds those baked in fields to their form they can pick the format (Input, Textarea, Select, Checkbox, or Radio). We need to be able to update the value of a targeted field (e.g. id="region") despite not knowing if it's going to be any of those input types before hand.

We thought there would be a small vanilla javascript solution on NPM available, but we weren't able to find one. Maybe it exist but we missed it?

In the end we came up with the following and Typescript but just wanted to see if anyone had any other known solutions. Hate to be reinventing the wheel if someone has already gone down this path.

```
// Set a value to any field. If it's a dropdown, radio or checkbox, it selects the proper option matching the value
setFieldValue(name: string, value: unknown) {
    (document.getElementsByName(name) as NodeListOf<HTMLFormElement>).forEach((field) => {
        if ('type' in field) {
            switch (field.type) {
                case 'select-one':
                case 'select-multiple':
                    for (const option of field.options) {
                        if (option.value == value) {
                            option.selected = true;
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'checkbox':
                case 'radio':
                    // @TODO: Try to trigger the onChange event
                    if (field.value == value) {
                        field.checked = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 'textarea':
                case 'text':
                default:
                    field.value = value;
            }
        }
    })
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A nice little Javascript library that works really well with ASP.NET WebForms is Alpine.js.   Basically what you could do is have all your various input controls bind to a model then work with the model rather than digging around the DOM for controls.